# Why am I getting an error when running a Sparkjob in Airflow?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm running a DAG in Airflow which sumbits a Sparkjob. Now when I trigger the DAG in the UI it fails and I receive below log. I dont see any error so I find it very hard to look for a solution. Im running Spark and Airflow in a docker-compose file.

Spark version = 3

Airflow version = 2.2.3

Im using windows 10

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/spark-test/spark_job/2022-02-01T15:36:24.688937+00:00/2.log
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1032} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: spark-test.spark_job manual__2022-02-01T15:36:24.688937+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1032} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: spark-test.spark_job manual__2022-02-01T15:36:24.688937+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1238} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1239} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 3
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1240} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1259} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitOperator): spark_job> on 2022-02-01 15:36:24.688937+00:00
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 224 to run task
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'spark-test', 'spark_job', 'manual__2022-02-01T15:36:24.688937+00:00', '--job-id', '18', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/spark-dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpxwwwi23v', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmp_jfwyn_j']
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 18: Subtask spark_job
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: spark-test.spark_job manual__2022-02-01T15:36:24.688937+00:00 [running]> on host 634e86891ac6
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1426} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=***@***.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=spark-test
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=spark_job
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-02-01T15:36:24.688937+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-02-01T15:36:24.688937+00:00
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {base.py:79} INFO - Using connection to: id: spark_default. Host: spark://spark, Port: 7077, Schema: , Login: , Password: None, extra: {}
[2022-02-01, 15:36:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:360} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master spark://spark:7077 --conf spark.master=spark://spark:7077 --name Spark Hello World --verbose /usr/local/spark/app/spark-book-count.py /usr/local/spark/data/book.txt
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - Using properties file: null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - Parsed arguments:
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - master                  spark://spark:7077
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - deployMode              null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - executorMemory          null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - executorCores           null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - totalExecutorCores      null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - propertiesFile          null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - driverMemory            null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - driverCores             null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - driverExtraClassPath    null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - driverExtraLibraryPath  null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - driverExtraJavaOptions  null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - supervise               false
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - queue                   null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - numExecutors            null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - files                   null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - pyFiles                 null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - archives                null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - mainClass               null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - primaryResource         file:/usr/local/spark/app/spark-book-count.py
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - name                    Spark Hello World
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - childArgs               [/usr/local/spark/data/book.txt]
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - jars                    null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - packages                null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - packagesExclusions      null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - repositories            null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - verbose                 true
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - Spark properties used, including those specified through
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - --conf and those from the properties file null:
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - (spark.master,spark://spark:7077)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - Main class:
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - Arguments:
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - file:/usr/local/spark/app/spark-book-count.py
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - null
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - /usr/local/spark/data/book.txt
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - Spark config:
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - (spark.master,spark://spark:7077)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - (spark.app.name,Spark Hello World)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - (spark.submit.pyFiles,)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - (spark.submit.deployMode,client)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - Classpath elements:
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 
[2022-02-01, 15:36:39 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.2.1
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: WordCount
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ***
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ***
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
[2022-02-01, 15:36:40 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:40 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(***); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(***); groups with modify permissions: Set()
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 41489.
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-0ff7687d-db4a-4122-bba8-322ce114aaf3
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 434.4 MiB
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://634e86891ac6:4040
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark:7077...
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to spark/172.18.0.4:7077 after 21 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20220201153641-0001
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20220201153641-0001/0 on worker-20220201153342-172.18.0.7-46557 (172.18.0.7:46557) with 1 core(s)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20220201153641-0001/0 on hostPort 172.18.0.7:46557 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 41249.
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 634e86891ac6:41249
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 634e86891ac6, 41249, None)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 634e86891ac6:41249 with 434.4 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 634e86891ac6, 41249, None)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 634e86891ac6, 41249, None)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 634e86891ac6, 41249, None)
[2022-02-01, 15:36:41 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:41 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20220201153641-0001/0 is now RUNNING
[2022-02-01, 15:36:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:42 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
[2022-02-01, 15:36:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:42 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
[2022-02-01, 15:36:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:42 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/app/spark-warehouse'.
[2022-02-01, 15:36:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-02-01, 15:36:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - File "/usr/local/spark/app/spark-book-count.py", line 7, in <module>
[2022-02-01, 15:36:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - inputDF = spark.read.text(r"C:\Users\JohnSmit\Desktop\tools\docker_env\***_and_spark\data\book.txt")
[2022-02-01, 15:36:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 346, in text
[2022-02-01, 15:36:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
[2022-02-01, 15:36:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
[2022-02-01, 15:36:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:%5CUsers%5CJohnSmit%5CDesktop%5Ctools%5Cdocker_env%5C***_and_spark%5Cdata%5Cbook.txt
[2022-02-01, 15:36:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:43 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
[2022-02-01, 15:36:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:44 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://634e86891ac6:4040
[2022-02-01, 15:36:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:44 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
[2022-02-01, 15:36:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:44 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
[2022-02-01, 15:36:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:44 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:45 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:45 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:45 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:45 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:45 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:45 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:45 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-974ac9a7-d3e5-4f20-bfa8-a8fd30d77030
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:45 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-01c651f5-1093-4a02-8148-96856465ea6e
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:514} INFO - 22/02/01 15:36:45 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-01c651f5-1093-4a02-8148-96856465ea6e/pyspark-1e260503-be05-4aac-8f16-54788ca0b795
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1700} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1329, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1455, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1511, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 182, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 446, in submit
    f"Cannot execute: {self._mask_cmd(spark_submit_cmd)}. Error code is: {returncode}."
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://spark:7077 --conf spark.master=spark://spark:7077 --name Spark Hello World --verbose /usr/local/spark/app/spark-book-count.py /usr/local/spark/data/book.txt. Error code is: 1.
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1277} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=spark-test, task_id=spark_job, execution_date=20220201T153624, start_date=20220201T153638, end_date=20220201T153645
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:92} ERROR - Failed to execute job 18 for task spark_job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/task/task_runner/standard_task_runner.py", line 85, in _start_by_fork
    args.func(args, dag=self.dag)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 298, in task_run
    _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 107, in _run_task_by_selected_method
    _run_raw_task(args, ti)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 184, in _run_raw_task
    error_file=args.error_file,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1329, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1455, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1511, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 182, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 446, in submit
    f"Cannot execute: {self._mask_cmd(spark_submit_cmd)}. Error code is: {returncode}."
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://spark:7077 --conf spark.master=spark://spark:7077 --name Spark Hello World --verbose /usr/local/spark/app/spark-book-count.py /usr/local/spark/data/book.txt. Error code is: 1.
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-02-01, 15:36:45 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: Did you solve this error? I'm facing something like that. It seems that:
ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
is getting called before the right time